AppleTV keeps asking for iCloud TOS Agreement
All of a sudden, my AppleTV (A1842 32GB on tvOS 18.0 22J357) started asking to agree to a new iCloud Terms of Service. But I don't actually want AppleTV to even connect to my iCloud. So I declined - but it keeps asking, even stopping movies to ask again and again.
So I went to Settings > Accounts > My Name > Apple Account > iCloud, but its greyed out.
On the same screen I went to Fotos, but it was and still is turned off.
How can I stop AppleTV asking for iCloud when I actually never allowed it to use it.
Thanks, Marco

Are there other Apple Accounts configured on your Apple TV?

Nope, just the one.
